# Wordpress function: Can't add a class to returned value

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am using a function that returns the content for specific posts of type 'product.' However, I want to check the length of the content, and if it is under a certain length, I would like to add a class to center the content (I have it left-aligned by default). I understand how to write the IF statement to check the length (so I left it out of the example). But I am having an issue returning the content with the class. Here is the function.

```
function post_product_description() {
   $product_title = get_the_title();
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'name' => $product_title
   ) ); 
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
     $content = get_the_content();
     $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
     //$content = '<span class="centered">'.$content.'</span>';
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   return $content;
}
add_shortcode('product_description', 'post_product_description');
```

If I just return the content as

`return $content`

it outputs the content in a `<p>` tag just fine like this:

```
 <p>the content text here</p>
```

However, if the length of the content exceeds a certain number, I want the `<span>` tag to output around the text like this:

`<span class="centered">the content text here</span>`

The problem is, if I try to append the `<span>` tags to my $content variable, as I am doing in the commented line in the original code, wordpress outputs like this:

```
<p><span class="centered"></span></p>
<p>the content outputs here</p>
<p></p>
```

How do I return $content without it adding all of those extras `<p>` tags and with it wrapping the `<span>` tag around the content?

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to add tags around the text returned by $content. However, if I do so, extra sets of `<p>` tags are added and the span doesn't wrap around the content.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like this:

*functions.php*

```
   add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

   function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() ):

        $length = strlen($content);
        if ($length> 500) //
        {
            $content = sprintf('<span class="custom-class">' .$content. '</span>');
        }

    endif;
    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
 }
```

This code will output the content wrapped inside **span class="custom-class"** you can check more about it at the Wordpress codex :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: I tried that, but I still couldn't get it to work. However, I got the following to work:
 `$content = '<span class="centered">'.get_the_content().'</span>';` I don't know why it suddenly started working because it appears to be the same thing that I was doing in my original post.